# Custmizing the UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I would like to set the color of the navigation bar on my app as well as the text color.

How does one do this?

I have seen people explaining methods where subviews are added to the bar, but there must be an easier(painstakingly) method.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Very untested (especially the last two lines may not always work, but if you play around with it you'll know if it does or not).

```
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
navigationController.topViewController.title = @"ye olde title";
UILabel *titleView = [navigationController.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
[titleView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Zapfino" size:10.f]];
```